# IJVM is IRETURN equal to HALT ? Because both stopps the interpreter?

Tags: ijvm, mic-1

I think `IRETURN` and `HALT` are the same commend in IJVM. Because I tried both and both stopped the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same (what would be the point of having two instructions doing the same thing?).

See the description in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJVM:

`HALT` is described as "Halt the simulator"

`IRETURN` is described as "Return from method with integer value"

If your code is running the top level method they may **appear** to have the same effect.

If you your top level method calls other methods you will see the distinction if the instructions are placed within the called methods:

- `HALT` will still halt the simulator, thereby aborting any ongoing calculations
- `IRETURN` will return from the called method to the caller